# "Parameter has wrong value type" when referencing Flow from VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I'm attempting to create a VisualForce page with a standard list controller that passes a list of custom objects (Feedback__c) to an SObject collection variable in a flow using the `{!selected}` syntax. The type for the VF page seems to match the SObject collection variable, but I receive the following error when opening the page.

> Parameter "feedbackCollection" has wrong value type.

[image]

I have confirmed that the correct flow is activated and the correct name is referenced. I am using a managed package namespace, which I have tried to prepend to object references in the VisualForce markup with the same result. Any guidance on why this error is occurring would be helpful.

Flow variable:

[image: feedbackCollection]

VisualForce page:

```
<!--Setting up the Visualforce Page-->
<apex:page standardController="Feedback__c" tabStyle="Feedback__c" recordSetVar="SelectedFeedback" >
    <!-- This is needed to 'display' the fields so that the Flow can read them.
    If there are any additional fields you want to send to the flow,
    add them after the existing fields. -->
    <apex:repeat value="{!SelectedFeedback}" var="f" rendered="false">
    {!f.Id} {!f.OwnerId}
    </apex:repeat>
    <!-- Setting your flow name in name, the finish location, and params
    use the param name of the flow with the value from the page,
    in this case the Selected Case records and the current User Id. --> 
    <flow:interview name="Accept_Feedback"
    finishLocation="{!IF($User.UITheme == 'Theme4d' || $User.UITheme == 'Theme4t','/one/one.app#/sObject/Feedback/home','/500')}">

        <!-- I REFERENCE THE COLLECTION VARIABLE HERE: -->
        <apex:param name="feedbackCollection" value="{!selected}"/>

        <apex:param name="myUserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that the object named in my standardController clause on line 1 of the VF page was not typed in the exact upper and lower case as the object.

Comment: I don't think controller names are case sensitive, but it could be that flows do some checking and aren't insensitive.